# MySql SELECT. Replace multiple columns in one shot

Tags: mysql, select

I want to make a SELECT which replaces the content of **multiple columns** from a table with the content from another table's single column.

There are two table TICKETS and USERS.

```
**TICKETS table**
ID opened_by closed_by
1  110       22
2  110       32
3  240       32

**USERS table**
ID    email
22    foo@mail.com
32    bar@mail.com
110   bob@mail.com
240   tom@mail.com

**THE UGLY SELECT RESULT**
ID opened_by          closed_by
1  bob@mail.com       foo@mail.com
2  bob@mail.com       bar@mail.com
3  tom@mail.com       bar@mail.com
```

Currently I am making a SELECT with LEFT JOIN of another SELECT with LEFT JOIN to get the result. The first SELECT replaces the opened_by column, and the second SELECT replaces the content of closed_by column like this:

```
SELECT x.ID, users.email AS opened_by, x.closed_by
   FROM (SELECT tickets.ID, tickets.opened_by, users.email AS closed_by
         FROM tickets
         LEFT JOIN users 
         ON tickets.closed_by=users.ID) as x 
   LEFT JOIN users 
   ON x.opened_by=users.ID;
```

Is it possible to have this same result using a single SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `tickets` to 2 copies of `users`:

```
select t.id, o.email opened_by, c.email closed_by
from tickets t
inner join users o on o.id = t.opened_by
inner join users c on c.id = t.closed_by
```

I used `INNER` joins, but if the columns `opened_by` and `closed_by` are nullable you should use `LEFT` joins